# document click bug? (firefox - windows)

Tags: jquery, windows, firefox

Here is the problem. **Firefox (Windows)** does not trigger document click event, when select is open. 
It just closes the select, and only next click will be counted as a click.

To reproduce:

1. Click select (the drop-down menu will appear)
2. Click outside the drop-down menu, on document outside (select will be closed)

However, the 2nd click won't trigger the document click event.

As you can see in this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzoTbRCLBUg), there are 3 clicks but 2 events.

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/AWYMb/)

**HTML**

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
var n = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      n++;
      $('#debug').text('select clicked ' + n);
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        n++;        
        $('#debug').text('document clicked '+ n);
    });
})
```

Comment: what version of Firefox do you use?

Comment: hm... i have 11... will try to update. but still it's strange

Comment: nope... ff13 same problem for me.

Comment: maybe it's a OS difference? mac/windows for example

Comment: maybe, using win... added video

Comment: Yep, the same "undexpected" behaviour. 2 clicks, 1 event (FF13, Win7)